# How to persist value from forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs6

I have a scenario where I have to get results of 2 http calls, and pass an array of their combined results to a class I am instantiating. Here is the code:

```
export class VideoListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: VideoListDataSource;
  constructor( private http: HttpProxyService, private videoService: VideoService ) { }
  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['Video Name', 'Author', 'Category Name', 'Highest Quality Format', 'Release Date', 'Options'];

  ngOnInit() {
    let observables = [this.videoService.getInitialData('movie-authors'), this.videoService.getInitialData('movie-categories')];
    forkJoin(observables).subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = new VideoListDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort, res);
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    })
  }

}
```

Now on the console.log I can see the value within `this.dataSource` as required, but when using it on the html template, it says that this.dataSource is undefined.

Any help? Am I missing something here?

**Edit with HTML markup**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: try like  :  <table *ngIf="dataSource" mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">

Comment: Yes all the works. I am getting the object in this.dataSource on console. But on HTML it throws error

Comment: because view is initialized before service gets called and that time dataSource is undefined

Comment: @programoholic that worked, but isn't angular change detection supposed to pick up the change?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to  and it does but mat-table is trying to populate data based on dataSource you provided and it's not able to render on undefined dataset.

Comment: Sure :) I will select it immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below :

```js
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table *ngIf="dataSource" mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
  </table>   
     ......
</div>
```

**Why my code is not working :**

> You are trying to populate table data using **datasource** which not initialized. datasource gets value from service .  Since the view is initialized before service gets called and that time **dataSource** is **undefined**, it is throwing the error.